# How to densify a sparse adjacency matrix?

Tags: sparse-matrices, adjacency-matrix

I have a sparse symmetric adjacency matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ that denotes an undirected graph.

How can I densify the matrix? I mean, how can I find a non-sparse matrix?

Is it OK to optimize the following objective function to find a dense matrix $\mathbf{U}$:
$\min\limits_{\mathbf{U}>0} {\lVert \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{UU}^T \rVert}_F^2+\lambda {\lVert \mathbf{U} \rVert}_1$
where $\mathbf{U} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\lambda$ is a regularization parameter, ${\lVert . \rVert}_F$ denotes frobenius norm and ${\lVert . \rVert}_1$ represents $L_1$-norm.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you :)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Presumably you want to find a non-sparse matrix which is related to your sparse matrix in some way, in order to accomplish something. How do you want it to be related to your spares matrix, and what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Though from the objective function it looks like you still want a sparse output $U$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I want to find a non-sparse matrix that preserves community structure of the sparse matrix.
In addition to the graph, there is a data matrix as meta-data.